# Arrange elements horizontally in a div with LESS

Tags: html, css, less, inline

I have a container with many squares with gradient background and I can't make these gradients display horizontally... How can I fix it ?

```
div.innerContainer {
    padding:5px;

    .purple {
        .size;
        .border-radius;
        .gradient(top, purple,);
    }
    .blue {
        .size;
        .border-radius;
        .gradient(top, blue;);                          
    }
    .green {
        .size;
        .border-radius;
        .gradient(top, green;)                          
    }
    .yellow {
        .size;
        .border-radius;
        .gradient(top, yellow;)
    }
    .orange {
        .size;
        .border-radius;
        .gradient(top, orange;) 
    }
    .red {
        .size;
        .border-radius;
        .gradient(top, red;)
    }
}
```

This is the div that is making the problem and here is the full code - http://jsfiddle.net/T2Xe9/376/.

Answer (score 1):

Your gradients currently begin from 'top'. Instead of this, to do a horizontal gradient, go to the right or to the left with 'to right' or 'to left'.

Here's an example:

```
.red {
    .size;
    .border-radius;
    .gradient(to right, red;)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use inline-block or use float property in your style for the boxes,
and if you are talking about the gradient to be displayed horizontally, then
update your mixin as it is not that flexible.

```
.gradient(@property, @v, @colour1, @colour2){
    @deg: unit(@v, deg);
    @{property}:-webkit-linear-gradient(@deg , @colour1 , @colour2);
    @{property}:linear-gradient(@deg , @colour1 , @colour2);
}
.box{
    .gradient(background-image, 45, blue 20%, red 100%);
    .gradient(border-image, 45, blue 20%, red 100%);
}
```